# FileNotFoundException - java test resources

Tags: java, testing, intellij-idea

I am writing `junit` tests, where I need to read a file from `src/test/resources`

I have a following code in my `src/test/java/some_packages/UserTests`:

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("abc.txt"));
```

The file is of course present, but when I run my test I get `java.io.FileNotFoundException: abc.txt (No such file or directory)`

I marked resources folder as test resources in intellij

Comment: Your question does not make much sense. Do you want to read a file (based on it's filename) or to read a resource from the classpath?

Comment: where is your abc.txt file stored? The problem is definitely the file is not found in the same directory as the compiled .class file.

Comment: I want to read abc.txt file , which is located under resources folder

Answer (score 12):

`new File("abc.txt")` is relative to the working directory for your tests, not the `src/test/resources` directory. To access resources in the `src/test/resources` directory, get the resource from the class loader:

```
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/abc.txt");
```